# AirSim in Microsoft Visual Studio: CMake can't find boost (missing boost_INCLUDE_DIR) and (missing boost_INCLUDE_DIR filesystem)

Tags: visual-studio, boost, cmake, airsim

For a project with friends I followed the instructions at this link( https://microsoft.github.io/AirSim/build_windows/#build-airsim ). But I can't go on to Build AirSim unless I fix these errors first.
The problem occurred after build.cmd.

The first error says: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion status Error CMake Error at C: / Program Files (x86) / Microsoft Visual Studio / 2019 / Community / Common7 / IDE / CommonExtensions / Microsoft / CMake / CMake / share / cmake- 3.20 / Modules / FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake: 230 (message): Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)`

The second one: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion status Error CMake Error at C: / Program Files (x86) / Microsoft Visual Studio / 2019 / Community / Common7 / IDE / CommonExtensions / Microsoft / CMake / CMake / share / cmake-3.20 / Modules / FindPackageHandleStandardArgs .cmake: 230 (message): Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR filesystem)` .

I have already tried to do it all over again and also tried some solutions found here on the site. Nothing seems to  work, I have been behind this for 7 hours in a row and I start to lose hope, I'm sure that probably the solution is basic but I have no idea what to do.
If you have any advice, I'm all ears

Comment: "I have already tried to do it all over again and also tried some solutions found here on the site." - So you most likely have **Boost** installed. Where (and how) have you installed it?

Comment: no i haven't tried to install it yet, it should install by itself i think when you do git code.  Before installing other stuff I wanted to ask here